# Example C Function using volatile variables

Tags: c, volatile

for a paper I'm looking for an *real-life* C function which uses volatile variables.  That in itself is not hard to find, but I am looking for a function in which the value of the volatile variable must change **during** the course of the execution of the function, for a particular branch of the function to be reached.  Something like this:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned       :6;
    unsigned FLAG1 :1;
    unsigned FLAG2 :1;
} __attribute__ ((packed)) REGISTER;

volatile REGISTER * io_ = 0x1234;

int write_to_io()
{
    while (io_->FLAG1) {};
    //io_->FLAG1 is now 0

    io_->FLAG2 = 1;

    sleep(10);

    if (io->FLAG1)  
        return 1;  //io->FLAG1 has changed from 0 to 1
    else
        return 0;  //io->FLAG1 has not changed
 }
```

It would be sufficient if different bits of the structure changed during the execution of the function, but my main criterion is that for a certain branch to be reached, the value of a volatile variable changes **during** the execution of the function.

I'd be very grateful for any real-life examples. I haven't been able to find many examples using volatile on the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some example of my teacher, which worked without volatile with one compiler (lcc), but breaked when i run it with my gcc port for that processor. I had to put volatile in.

```
static int volatile busTimeoutSeen;

int busTimeoutISR(int irq) {
  busTimeoutSeen = 1;
  return 1;  /* skip offending instruction */
}


int memsize(void) {
  unsigned char volatile *ptr;
  unsigned char b;
  ISR oldService;

  busTimeoutSeen = 0;
  oldService = getISR(16);
  setISR(16, busTimeoutISR);
  ptr = (unsigned char *) 0xC0000000;
  while (1) {
    b = *ptr;
    if (busTimeoutSeen) {
      break;
    }
    ptr += (1 << 12);
  }
  setISR(16, oldService);
  return (ptr - (unsigned char *) 0xC0000000) >> 12;
}
```

It reads continuously from all pages, until we get past the last page, which causes an interrupt, which will set `busTimeoutSeen` to 1. As that happens behind the scenes, we tell the compiler to read and write the data always to memory.

Comment: Many thanks litb, this example will do nicely. In the function memsize, the busTimeoutSeen has to change from 0 to non-zero __during the execution of the function__, for the function to complete.

Answer (score 8):

The canonical (and portable) example is handling an asynchronous signal.  (You can probably deliver SIGINT to your program with Ctrl-C).

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t quit;

void signal_handler(int sig)
{
    signal(sig, signal_handler);
    quit = 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
    puts("Hit return to poll quit flag");
    while (!quit) getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Pick your favorite open source operating system, and look for old device drivers, you'll find some who have no other way of working.

Answer (score 0):

Memory mapped IO is an example where a value in memory may actually represent reading from a device such as a COM port.  When I learned C, this was one of the examples given for the use of the volatile keyword.